# how to give no-more-use of css in jquery for css params

Tags: jquery, css

this is the css we do

```
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #f00;
```

and when we want to give no-more-use of the css we could add just a slash or anything that css doesn't understand but all other css works

```
widt/h: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #f00;
```

but I wanted to do it in jquery like `marginLef/t` in jquery which didn't work anymore all other params.

**sample jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("h2").animate({backgroundColor: '#00f', width: '-=150px', marginLef/t: '50px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you just delete it ??

Comment: this would be in use next time.

Comment: Show please jquery code, that you tried.

Comment: why don't you just comment out the unused parts? `/* comments are your friends */`

Comment: Introducing errors to cause code to be ignored only works in an environment where errors are ignored. Errors in Javascript will keep the script from running, so you can't use that method there.

Comment: @C-Link, try to set "margin-lef\t" (in quotes) instead of marginLef\t

Comment: Erm that is the *"give your kid a gun and he will shoot himself"* solution. Please for the love of god use comments instead.

Comment: I know the way we comment but I have put this question so that next time jquery developer will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of breaking your code, use comments. For CSS:

```
/* width: 200px; this rule is obsolete for now */
height: 100px;
background-color: #f00;
```

In Javascript:

```
alert('this line is executed');
// alert('this line is not');
/* removed following line in a multiline comment
alert('also not being executed');
*/
```

Commenting ensures the values are not being parsed as a whole, and that it cannot break the parser/compiler and as such other functionality.

While CSS standards explicitly define that a malformed rule should be ignored, and other valid rules still applied, in a compiler language like Javascript it just breaks execution as a whole.

Comment: I know the way we comment but I have put this question so that next time jquery developer will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier by making two different classes, other with the width and one without. Then just change the elements' class with jQuery using addClass and removeClass or toggleClass.